# access namespace when laravel project inside another project

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I have an existing project:

```
/project
     /utils
     /tests
     /database
     /...
```

I want to add an api server so I can access parts of the system via http.
I therefore want to add a laravel project in an /api subdirectory of my project:

```
/project
     /utils
     /tests
     /database
     /api    --> laravel should be inside this folder
     /...
```

Now I want to access classes of my project from laravel.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return Utils\StringUtils::isEmpty('asd');
});
```

but I get:

```
Class 'Utils\StringUtils' not found
```

This is probably because the laravel project has its own namespace. How can I reference classes from my actual procject?

Comment: Assuming you're using composer in the laravel part, I believe you should be able to put the mapping for those folders under the autoload -> psr4 (or perhaps psr0)? https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the path to your Laravel namespace in your `composer.json` `autoload` section:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "ProjectApi\\": "project/api/"
    },
  }
```

And run `composer dumpautoload`